# Is there any difference between MySQL specific implementation of SQL and ANSI SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

Is there any difference between MySQL specific implementation of SQL and ANSI SQL?
And if there is, how is MySQL SQL dialect called?

Comment: Lots of differences.  I think the MySQL documentation covers it pretty well.

Comment: @ObsidianAge the first one is not a duplicate, since it is about the difference between a programming language and an rdbms product. The second one would be a duplicate if it had an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: Short anwer: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql differs from the standard SQL programming language in several ways. Mysql documentation has a separate section on [standards compliance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/compatibility.html).

Mysql's own SQL implementation does not have a separate name like Oracle's pl/sql.